# item tag requires a 'drawable' attribute

Tags: android, xml

Hello I need Help because i am getting the error item tag requires a 'drawable' attribute
card_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="18dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

my card_background_selector.xml which i get that error from is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@drawable/card_background"></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: i guess problem for `android:color`

Comment: let me confirm if you set `android:color="#54d66a"` then ??

Comment: what should i put instead of android:color?

Comment: i have tried `<item android:drawable="@drawable/card_background" />` but still

Comment: Still i get the Error @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: do this `<item android:drawable="@drawable/card_background"
   android:state_selected="true" />`

Comment: still man i am getting an error @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 0):

what type of the image you selected? is the main issue. if your image is not in png format you will get the error.